# From within a Visual Studio extension, how can I determine which Visual Studio updates are installed?

Tags: visual-studio, envdte, vsx

I would like to determine whether VS2013 Update 2 is installed from within a VSPackage. What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb164659(v=vs.120).aspx. for the updates, you probably can use the same mechanism they have for detecting updates for VS2012.

Comment: That registry path (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\12.0\) has an "SP" property for which Visual Studio Service Pack is used, but Service Packs have been abandoned in favor of Updates, so in VS2012/VS2013 it is always 0.

Comment: for update 1/2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\Microsoft Visual Studio 2013\vsupdate_KB2829760